# Copying data in and out of Snowflake via Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to copy into blob storage and then copy out of blob storage. The copy into works:

```sql
copy into 'azure://my_blob_url.blob.core.windows.net/some_folder/MyTable'
    from (select *
          from MyTable
          where condition = 'true')
    credentials = (azure_sas_token = 'my_token');
```

But the copy out fails:

```sql
copy into MyTable
    from 'azure://my_blob_url.blob.core.windows.net/some_folder/MyTable'
    credentials = (azure_sas_token = 'my_token');
```

the error is:

`SQL Compilation error: Function 'EXTRACT' not supported within a COPY`.

Weirdly enough, it worked *once* and hasn't worked since. I'm at a loss, nothing turns up details for this.

I know there's an approach I could take using stages, but I don't want to for a bunch of reasons and even when I try with stages the same error presents itself.

Edit:

The cluster key definition is:

`cluster by (idLocal, year(_ts), month(_ts), substring(idGlobal, 0, 1));`

where the `idLocal` and `idGlobal` are `varchar`s and the `_ts` is a `TIMESTAMPTZ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've seen this before with a cluster key on the table (which I don't think is supported with COPY INTO).  The EXTRACT function (shown in the error) being part of the CLUSTER BY on the table.

This is a bit of a hunch, but assuming this isn't occurring for all your tables, hoping it leads to investigation on the table configuration and perhaps that might help.

Comment: Thanks, we do use clustering on this particular table. I wonder if there a way around that?

Comment: This doesn't explain why it worked one random time, though.

Comment: Maybe your cluster key was added after the one random time?  Also, could you share the definition of your cluster key?  Your options are to use a different function or load the file into a temp table first.

Comment: No, the cluster key wasn't added after that, I know that for 100% certainty.

Comment: @MikeWalton I've updated the question with the cluster key definition.

Comment: Playing around with this a bit more, it does seem like it's the clustering that causes the problem. If I first copy into a `MyTable_No_Clustering` and then `insert` from the no cluster table into the clustered table, it works just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I know that Snowflake Dev is working on supporting all SQL functions with COPY statements, but in the meantime you'll need to workaround.  If it worked once, you could try checking the account_usage query_history to see if you changed the table or cluster key at all between when it was successful and unsuccessful. That's all I got but glad we could pinpoint where the issue was.

Comment: When it worked the one time I checked the history and nothing had changed. The one time it ran I didn't have the FORCE flag on it may have been that nothing actually imported

Comment: I spoke with Snowflake about this directly. It's on their roadmap, for now they recommend creating a table like the original table, dropping the cluster by key, copying into there. Then, insert into from selecting from the similar table.

Answer (score 0):

Alex can you try with a different function in the cluster key on your target table like date_trunc('day',_ts)?

thanks
Chris

Comment: Sure Chris, this results in a similar problem: `SQL Compilation error: Function 'TRUNCTIMESTAMPTOYEAR' not supported within a COPY`